# Why does Windows 8 not detect all my cores after a processor upgrade?

Tags: windows-8, cpu

I got a new CPU and installed it.  Everything seems to be working fine, except that Windows 8 appears to not detect all the cores.

For example, if I enter  `WMIC CPU get /Format:List`

I get `Name= AMD Athlon(TM) X4 760k Quad core processor`, but `NumberOfCores = 2` and `NumberOfLogicalProcessors=4`

Is it a problem of detection, OS limitation, or something else?  And how do I get all of the cores to be used?
Edit: after further research I found out that this processor has no hyperthreading. Windows 8 is detecting 4 logical processes and it has 4 cores so it looks like I am good to go.

Comment: What does your bios say about the CPU?

Comment: Also if you go to device manager what is listed under Processors?

Comment: If I go into device manager it lists 4 AMD Athlon(TM) X4 760k Quad core processors. Also cpu-z lists 4 cores.

Comment: Hmmm that is odd, what about if you got to task manager and check performance then run some stuff does it have four cores all being used?

Comment: Task manager has 2 cores 4 logical processors.

Comment: Is it possibly a limitation of the version of windows your using?  I have anecdotally heard that some versions (home) of Windows limits the number of cores you can actually use.  I could be mistaken.

Comment: My thoughts are that it is most likely using the cores even if its not showing like it is however its hard to really say. There are some methods to reset the CPU count in Windows (only ever done in Windows 7) which did work well for me when I had the same issue. The tool is called EasyBCD and you have to modify Windows slightly to get this to work, I would give step by step as an answer however its very risky and not a confirmed as a fixed so wouldn't like to be responsible for causing more issues. Google EasyBCD reset CPU count Windows there are plenty of guides to see if you want to try.

Comment: In fact reading one of the guides does state what you see: 
Notes: Some of these discrepancies will appear if your OS is reading the incorrect amount of cores. 
1) Device Manager will show the correct amount of Cores for the PC after the new CPU is installed even tho Task Manager still shows the old amount of cores. This is why you need to preform these steps above to fix this disparity and enable the OS to work with the new additional core.

Comment: Check `MSConfig` > Boot > Advanced options > Number of processors.  If it's check-marked, un-check it and reboot.

Comment: I did that already, it did not seem to help